# Getting value of attribute value from XML document

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm using Editix to run some XML queries, and I'm trying to get the "role" attribute from the  tags...

```
<actor id="5" role="Richie Cusack"/>
```

....and insert the value in between  tags that I generate, like so....

```
<role>Richie Cusack</role>
```

...but the query I'm running is inserting the role attribute value back into an attribute of the tags I surround it with, like...

```
<role role="Richie Cusack"/>
```

Here's my XQuery query....

```
<results>
{
let $ms := doc("xmlPath.xml"),
for $m in $ms//movie
    for $r in $m/actor/@role
    return <result>
        {$m/title}<role>{$r}</role>
         </result>
}
</results>
```

...and here's the structure of the XML file...

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <summary>Tom Stall, a humble family man and owner of a 
    .</summary>
    <director id="1"/>
    <actor id="5" role="Richie Cusack"/>
 </movie>
  <movie>
    <title>Heat</title>
    <year>1995</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <summary>Hunters and their prey--Neil and his professional 
    .... </summary>
    <director id="6"/>
    <actor id="7" role="Lt. Vincent Hanna"/>
</movies>
```

How can I extract only the value of an attribute and embed it in between tags without it inserting itself in the form of an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within this query, `$r` itself is an attribute, so that is being added to the parent node, `<role>` (you can note that the same thing is happening with `$m/title` - the element itself, and not just its text, is being added to `<result>`).

To get the behavior you are looking for, do this:

```
<role>{string($r)}</role>
```